# JSP can not recognize struts2 tags

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I am fresh to struts2 and have a basic issue. 
I've added struts-tags declaration:

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
```

but my eclipse still can not recognize the struts tag. The code is:

```
<s:if test='oper != "add"'>
  ,{
     xtype: 'fieldset',
```

and the error is:

> Syntax error on token ","

Also I have added the `struts 2.1` library.

Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: Eclipse is not good at parsing JSPs, nevermind. On the other hand, beware of the way you compare Strings... *that*'s erroneous

Comment: What is this `,{    xtype: 'fieldset',` ?